# how to initialise two datatables in one page?

Tags: datatable, datatables

i have two different tables on one page and i using two different datatable plugins for both as number of columns are different in both and export options are varying for both as per columns.
Please suggest how can i initialize both as only the first is being initialized as of now.
In the below code, table1 is being initialized properly however table2 is not.

```
$('#table1').DataTable({
        dom: 'frBtip<"clear">l\'',
        language: {"Search": "Filter"},
        paging: true,
        info: true,
        scrollX: true,
        scrollY: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        pageLength:0,
        buttons: [
            {
                extend:    'excelHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                className: 'btn-success',
                titleAttr: 'Excel',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21]
                }
            },
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: [2,3,4,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,19],
                visible: false
            }
        ]

    });
$('#table2').DataTable({
        dom: 'frBtip<"clear">l\'',
        language: {"Search": "Filter"},
        paging: true,
        info: true,
        scrollX: true,
        scrollY: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        pageLength:0,
        buttons: [
            {
                extend:    'excelHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                className: 'btn-success',
                titleAttr: 'Excel',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
                }
            },
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: [2,3,4,9],
                visible: false
            }
        ]

    });
```

Comment: Some notes: (1) If I comment out both of your `pageLength:0,` options then both tables are initialized OK - and I can see my test data, as confirmation. (2) I was not sure what the purpose of the `1\'` was in each `dom` option - just out of curiosity.

Comment: Bottom line: I am unable to reproduce the problem using your code. Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Where is your HTML? You also do not initialize your columns under your table. Have you checked out the tabbed datatables option.